# Find value upwards using reverse index+match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I Have to find first zero(cell C3) upward in column C from cell D7,D12 and D15

how to find first Zero value upwards in **C** column. is there any way something like reverse Hlookup, INDEX+Match. please advise.

[image]

Comment: =LOOKUP(2,1/($C$2:C2=0),$B$2:B2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($C$2:C2=0),$B$2:B2)
```